# Storing data in memory for fast access in web api

Tags: dictionary, asp.net-web-api, static-variables

In the web api, data is inserted/updated into database based on the response received from another service called from this web api serivce.

For fast access to this web api by its client, the data from another services are also stored in static IDictionary<> so that those data can be quickly searched and no need to query to database. Another thing is, Once the client receive their data (based upon their initial transaction on request) then these are no longer useful and no need to still store in that memory as that transaction is finished after this and finished the overall task.

Now my question is: I am worried about using the static IDictionary and looking for another good approach of doing such things.

I would appreciate the answer. Thanks